# 'Window' object has no attribute '_tclCommands'

Tags: python, tkinter, window, runtime-error

I'm new to Python and am trying to make a code for class that needs either to clear the screen or make new windows, which I have tried both of but failed miserably. But besides that, I have tried to run this code with different modifications, and almost all the time I get the error: 'Window' object has no attribute '_tclCommands'. What does this error mean? Another thing that could be related to this is that I cannot close the window specifically, but instead need to quit out of IDLE, the error saying: 'Window' object has no attribute 'destroy'. What can I do to fix this?

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import os

background_color = 'SlateGray'
text_background_color = 'DarkViolet'

class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.configure(background = background_color)

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.button = Button(self, text = "Clear", command = clear_screen())
        self.button.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    def clear_screen(self):
        self.Frame.grid_forget()



root = Tk()
root.configure(background = background_color)
root.title("Guess Your Birthday")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what is _tclCommand?

Comment: I have no idea, that's why I am asking

Comment: where does is happen? have you tried debugging?

Comment: I found my problem. The code didn't like that I didn't have (Frame) next to Window

Comment: I presume what you meant, for tkinter newbies reading your comment, is that you did not derive Window from Frame, but you used Window as if it were a tk widget, and hence the error message.  I suspect that the unposted traceback showed 'self.grid' as the failing line.

Comment: You can't call `Frame.__init__` if you don't inherit from `Frame`. You also can't use `self` as a parent for other windows if `self` doesn't represent a widget.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to inherit from `Frame` because your class is missing some of the common methods a Tkinter widget has:

```
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()
    self.configure(background = background_color)
```

`grid()` and `configure()` have not yet been implemented in your class, right? So there lies your problem, **you need to subclass a Tkinter widget class** to have all those nice methods:

```
    class Window(Frame):
```

Answer (score 0):

Idle is written with Tkinter I am told and so running Tkinter programs in Idle can cause problems, i.e. run it from the command line or another IDE.  There are many problems with your program and it is easier to create a working program than to go over each error individually.  The Effbot site is a good place to start learning Tkinter as it has simple examples for each widget http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/

```
class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.fr=Frame(master)
        self.fr.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        background_color = 'SlateGray'
        text_background_color = 'DarkViolet'
        self.fr.configure(background = background_color)

        self.tl=Toplevel(master)
        Button(self.tl, text = "Remove TopLevel",
               command=self.clear_tl).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.button = Button(self.fr, text = "Clear Frame",
                            command=self.clear_screen)
        self.button.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    def clear_screen(self):
        self.fr.grid_forget()

    def clear_tl(self):
        self.tl.destroy()  ## removes the window

root=Tk()    
##root.configure(background = background_color)
root.title("Guess Your Birthday")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```